# Sylius : An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("") in @SyliusShop\Product\Show\_inventory.html.twig at line 4

Tags: sylius

i have this exception :

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("") in @SyliusShop\Product\Show_inventory.html.twig at line 4.
500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime
1 linked Exception: NotFoundHttpException »

and this is the file that throws the exception : 
**ShopBundle/Resources/views/Product/Show/_inventory.html.twig:**

```
    {% if product.simple and not sylius_inventory_is_available(product.firstVariant) %}
    {% include '@SyliusShop/Product/Show/_outOfStock.html.twig' %}
{% else %}
    {% render(url('sylius_shop_cart_item_add', {'template': '@SyliusShop/Product/Show/_addToCart.html.twig', 'productId': product.id})) %}
{% endif %}
```

**ShopBundle/Resources/config/routing/cart.yml:**

```
sylius_shop_cart_item_add:
path: /add
methods: [GET, POST]
defaults:
    _controller: sylius.controller.cart_item:addAction
    _sylius:
        factory:
            method: createForProduct
            arguments: [expr:service('sylius.repository.product').find($productId)]
        form:
            type: sylius_cart_item
            options:
                product: expr:service('sylius.repository.product').find($productId)
        template:  $template
        redirect:
            route: sylius_shop_cart_summary
            parameters: {}
        flash: sylius.cart.item_add_completed
```

i make sure that the product id is not null , what can be the problem ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks like you're calling url('sylius_shop_cart_item_add') even though this is the route name. Wouldn't the url be '/add'?

Comment: no i dont think so , i've an other route  calling like this and it works fine , i've actually post this issue on github and it was labled as a bug :
https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/6532

Comment: Oh I see, great glad you reported it and it's been added to the bug list. Cheers!

Comment: thx :) , i want to ask you if routes are generated in admin panel or not ?